# Can we enter the UK with Blue Cards issued by Romania?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, eu-citizens, residency

I am an Irish national and my non-EU wife and son (Indian) have EU family cards issued by Romania (long-term residency valid for 5 years). Can my son and wife travel to the UK for a few days with me to watch a soccer match?

Comment: You can find out here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Comment: This is an other site you can use to check whether they need visa: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

Answer (score 1):

I have an EU Blue Card and I am pretty sure that your family will need a Visa to travel to the UK. Most of the websites where you need to check the availability of Visa for travel do not state exceptions if one holds **EU Blue Cards/Green Cards** etc. The main basis for entry depends solely on the fact that which Passport you bear.

In a synonymous situation, if you are an American Green Card holder but you still have a passport that requires a Visa to travel to a certain country; you will still need to apply for a Visa.